# Looking for free/paid RSS to GeoRSS converters

Tags: software-recommendations, georss

I am looking for an RSS to GeoRSS converters. I was able to find only one converter i.e. [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/rss-to-georss-converter.html) (it's crashing sometimes) and [Meta-carta](http://www.metacarta.com/) (looks like closed)

So does anyone knows free/paid RSS to GeoRSS converters?

Software: ArcGIS Suit 10.1 & ArcGIS JSAPI 3.3/3.4

Comment: What do you mean by RSS to GeoRSS convertor? GeoRSS is a superset of RSS. What location information do you want to add to the RSS feed?

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe I need lat,lon information of the contents in the feed I am plotting those information on the map using ArcGISJSAPI sample(https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/layers_georss.html). I tried to insert simple xml url in the sample but unable to display points on the map.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe That's the reason I am using GeoNames (RSS to GeoRSS converter).

Comment: My question is: What is the current content of your RSS? Is the location contained in the name of a city/ state/ PIN code? or what? What accuracy is acceptable to you, when converting from this name to a location?

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe Thanks for the reply. I am not sure regarding  location criteria but it might taking country name. My xml url is :http://www.zawya.com/rssfeeds/oil_gas.xml

Comment: Looking at your RSS feed,  I don't see any direct location in it. The news item might be from a particular location, but parsing the title to extract even the Location as just text, will be a hard task; Only once you have that, can you convert to a lat long.